# Hibernate mapping of a threefold relationship

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

How do I map this?

```
public class Survey {
long id; 
Map<Question, Answer> questionnaire; ...
```

what I'd like is to have a table (say QUESTIONNAIRE) 
that'll bear the three ids (SURVEY_ID, QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<map name="questionnaire" table="QUESTIONNAIRE">
  <key column="SURVEY_ID" />
  <index-many-to-many class="...Question" column="QUESTION_ID" />
  <one-to-many class="...Answer" column="ANSWER_ID" />
</map>
```